# Restoring SQL Server Backup file

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-restore, sql-server-2014

I have a .bak file from Microsoft Sql version 8.i want to restore this file to Microsoft SQL Server 2014. But there is a problem:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Restore of database 'asset' failed.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The database was backed up on a server
>   running version 8.00.0384. That version is incompatible with this
>   server, which is running version 12.00.2000. Either restore the
>   database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is
>   compatible with this server. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
>
> For help, click:
>   [http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8+((SQL14_RTM).140220-1752)&LinkId=20476](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8+%28%28SQL14_RTM%29.140220-1752%29&LinkId=20476)

How can I restore a .bak file (version 8) in MSSQL 2014?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about database backup and restore and doesn't involve any programming related tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. you can't restore a backup from version 8 to version 12. you can restore created backup from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014 without any problem and with upgrade automatically.

I suggest you to generate script of schema and data from your database and execute created script in new version of sql server.

In order to create script in SQL Server 2008 and above version, use `Database\Tasks\Generate scripts` and select `schema and data` on `Types of data to script` advanced option.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot restore a backup done by old version to new one.

Your options are:

- upgrade old version of SQL Server
- restore the backup you have on a compatible version ,export all the
  data and import it on the new instance.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Within defined limits a backup from an older SQL Server version **can indeed** be restored to a newer SQL Server version.  For example SQL Server 2000 can be restored to SQL Server 2008 R2, but not to more recent versions.